# In contraceptive effectiveness ratings, are “typical use,” and “perfect use” self-reported?

Tags: sex, effectiveness, clinical-study, contraception

The effectiveness of contraception methods is typically reported as two percentages: *typical use* and *perfect use*.

**Typical use** is the measure of how the average couple is likely to use the method, and takes into account incorrect or inadequate application. For example: an inside-out condom, or a missed day of birth control pills.

**Perfect use** assumes the couples being studies used the contraceptive method exactly as directed, without errors.

**How are participants partitioned into these two groups?**

Is there typically one large study, and participants self-report if they did not meet perfect use?

Are two groups formed prior to the study's start, and given differing levels of instruction?

Or something else?